# Center element inside qml ColumnLayout

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

How to center element inside qml **ColumnLayout**? I unsuccessfully tried:

```
Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
```

code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ColumnLayout{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width
        Layout.preferredHeight:  parent.height
        visible: true

        Text{
            id: myText
            text: "My Text"
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
            Layout.preferredHeight: 25
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
        }
    }
}
```

But myText is still not horizontally centered. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we review with the Quick Designer we obtain the following:

[image]

As we see the item is centered. The problem is that Layout does not handle the position of the text inside the Text item, for this you must use [`horizontalAlignment`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#horizontalAlignment-prop):

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.11
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ColumnLayout{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.width
        Layout.preferredHeight:  parent.height
        visible: true

        Text{
            id: myText
            text: "My Text"
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
            Layout.preferredHeight: 25
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
    }
}
```

[image]